# REGEX help needed for deleting certain lines

Tags: regex, sed

I understand why

```
echo abc 123 xyz|sed "/abc\s*\d*\s*$/d"
```

produces

```
abc 123 xyz
```

because the pattern is abc followed by 0 or more white space followed by 0 or more digits followed by 0 or more white space followed by end of line and the data doesn't match that spec because of the xyz characters.

Why does

```
echo abc 123  |sed "/abc\s*\d*\s*$/d"
```

produce

```
abc 123
```

instead of null output because the data does match the pattern?

Comment: This seems like a helpful link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12178924/os-x-sed-e-doesnt-accept-extended-regular-expressions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `\d` is not a character class that `sed` supports:

```
$ echo abc 123  |sed '/abc\s*\d*\s*$/d'
abc 123
```

Use `[:digit:]` instead:

```
$ echo abc 123  |sed '/abc\s*[[:digit:]]*\s*$/d'
$
```

`\d` is available as a regex extension in languages such as perl or python.  The regex syntax that `sed` supports is more basic. For an overview of the regex syntax supported by GNU `sed`, see [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Regular-Expressions).

Note that `[:digit:]` will work with unicode fonts while `[0-9]` will not.  Consequently, all new code should use `[:digit:]`.

#### Character classes supported by `sed` regular expressions

POSIX `sed` is documented [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/utilities/sed.html).  POSIX requires `sed` to support Basic Regular Expressions (BREs).  The POSIX spec for BREs is [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html#tag_09_03) and specifies that, including `[:digit:]`, `sed` regular expressions must support the following character classes in all locales:

```
[:alnum:]   [:cntrl:]   [:lower:]   [:space:]
[:alpha:]   [:digit:]   [:print:]   [:upper:]
[:blank:]   [:graph:]   [:punct:]   [:xdigit:]
```

[GNU's `sed`](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Regular-Expressions) offers several extensions.  This includes `\w` for "word" characters, meaning alphanumeric and underline, and `\b` which matches at a word boundary.  As Bill Gradwohl observed, `\s`, signifying white space, works under GNU `sed` but is *not* mentioned in the documentation.

Comment: I tried man sed and it was useless. I tried man regex and it wasn't much better. According to your link, \s also isn't supported by sed.

Comment: @BillGradwohl Good observation.  I couldn't find `\s` in GNU's docs either.  I updated the answer with more information on supported character classes and links to POSIX `sed` documentation.

Answer (score 1):

The `sed` program has limited support for certain regex constructs, specifically `\d`. You can get around this by using something like `[0-9]` instead.

Or, since finding or removing lines is more the purview of `grep`, you can use *it* to do the work for you. Assuming you have `GNU grep`, it can do Perl regexes quite well:

```
echo abc 123  | grep -Pv "abc\\s*\\d*\\s*$"
```

If you *have* to use `sed` because, for example, there are a number of complex commands you need to execute on each line, feel free to ignore this advice. Otherwise, my suggestion is to choose the more appropriate tool for the job.

Answer (score 1):

A work around for `\d`

```
echo abc 123  |sed "/abc\s*[0-9]*\s*$/d"
```