# Why does echo 'hello world' | awk '/hello\s/ {print $0}' produce nothing?

Tags: regex, linux, macos, awk

Why does  this 'awk' command produce nothing?

```
   echo 'hello world' | awk '/hello\s/ {print $0}'
```

I suppose the pattern /hello\s/  should match any line that has 'hello' followed by a whitespace, right?

For info, I am using awk in a Mac OS. The awk version is 20070501.

Comment: I doesn't produce nothing here (GNU awk). Are you using an awk that doesn't recognize `\s`, as for example mawk?

Comment: I use `gawk` and it works... as Benjamin says, `\s` is not available in the 'plain' awk.

Comment: @Benjamin Does your mawk mean the awk in Mac OS?

Comment: @kwinkunks But the awk manual claims they accept standard reg expression.

Comment: `\s` was (I think) invented by *perl*. Your awk uses regular expressions as defined here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man7/re_format.7.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/7/re_format

Comment: Mawk is "Mike's awk". Not sure about BSD awk, but it looks like `\s` is a GNUism.

Comment: @glennjackman I learned Regex from http://regexone.com/. Do you mean the  regex on that page is different from the re-format you refer to?

Comment: @zell, there are many different implementations of regular expression engines. Just about every programming language writes their own. They are *mostly* the same, but there are differences. If you're using regex in tool X you really need to consult X's documentation

Comment: @BenjaminW., I see in that re_format man page that there are "enhanced" regular expressions that include the usual shortcut escapes, but the tool would have to have that included as a compile-time option, and you'd expect the tool's documentation to state the use of enhanced regexes

Comment: @glennjackman: Indeed. The only OSX utility (as of OSX 10.11.3) that I've found to support the _enhanced_ flavor  is `grep`. (Also note that _enhanced_ is independent of _basic_ vs. _extended_, and that there are _enhanced extended_ as well as _enhanced basic_ regexes; see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23146221/45375) of mine.)

Comment: It's really frustrating how regex is a multiverse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works on OS X:

```
echo 'hello world' | awk '/hello[[:space:]]/ {print $0}'
```

As mentioned in the [gawk docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/GNU-Regexp-Operators.html) (paraphrasing):

> Think of `\s` like shorthand for `[[:space:]]`

You can also use `[[:blank:]]` to limit to space and tab only.

Having trouble finding some 'plain' awk docs. [This seems legit](http://www.math.utah.edu/docs/info/gawk_5.html), despite the name of the page.

Comment: Nicely done; note, however, that you're linking to a _GNU_ Awk documentation page. The BSD `awk`'s man page on OSX refers to `man re_format` for the supported regex features, but, unfortunately, `awk` does _not_ support all the features described there, notably not `[[:<:]]` and `[[:>:]]` for word-boundary assertions.

Comment: @glennjackman has found the online version of `man re_format`: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man7/re_format.7.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/7/re_format

Comment: This is an old answer, but I thought I'd point out that even `gawk` didn't recognize `\s` as a shorthand for `[[:space:]]` [until version 4](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Feature-History.html). I just came across this problem on an old CentOS 6.3 machine, which has version 3.1.7 installed.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo 'hello world' | awk  '/^hello / {print $0}'
```

This looks for every line that starts with "hello "

Comment: But only if followed by a space, but not a tab, which `\s` would match.

Comment: You are right. But the question was for white space.

Comment: Yes, but whitespace and `\s` both include tabs.

Comment: And the character classes `[:space:]` and `[:blank:]` both include spaces and tabs.