RegEx to find characters at specific positions
I have a series of dates formatted in a yy MM dd style:
981105
030730
140228
240422

I would like to use a sequence of regular expressions to parse these out by matching first the year, then the month and then the day.
I figured out how to match the first two digits:
^\d{1}[0-9]

But I’m stumped from there. Any help would be appreciated.

Why use a regular expression? Just split the string into pairs of digits.

BTW, why not \d{2} for the first two digits?

That's crazy. \d is effectively equivalent to [0-9] and the repetition operator {1} does nothing at all. You want \d{2} or \d\d (or [0-9]{2}) to match two digits.

Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44812906/bash-regular-expression-that-will-match-yymmdd-but-not-longer-numbers or etc. Though you haven't specified which regex implementation you want this for; but it should not be hard to find a duplicate for any one of them. Going forward, please search before asking.

Use capture groups to extract each pair of digits:
\b(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})\b

Capture group 1 contains the year, group 2 contains the month, group 3 contains the day.

The fact that you wish to break the string into year, month and day suggests you may wish to use that information in further calculations (as opposed, for example, to just printing out those three values). If so you may wish to convert the string to a date object, provided your computer language provides that support. That is discussed below, but first we need to specify the year represented by the first two characters of the date string.

In your first example, '981105', '98' could refer to the year 1995, 2095 or 1195. If, for example, the earliest possible year was determined to be 1990 and the last possible year were 2089, you might expand the string from 6 to 8 digits with with a method such as the following (in Ruby, which you can view as pseudo-code).
def date_string_with_full_year(date_string)
  year = date_string[2].to_i
  if year >= 1990 and year < 2000
    date_string = "19" + date_string
  else
    date_string = "20" + date_string
  end
end

For example,
date_string_with_full_year('981105')
  #=> "19981105"

date_string_with_full_year('240422')
  #=> "20240422"


Many computer languages follow C's example by providing the means to convert this 8-character string to a date object (or to otherwise treat the string as representing a date), which can then be manipulated in many ways.
In Ruby, for example, this would be done using the method Date::strptime.
require 'date'

d = Date.strptime('20240422', '%Y%m%d')
  #=> #<Date: 2024-04-22 ((2460423j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>

'%Y%m%d' is a format string, where '%Y', '%m' and '%d' have special meanings (which are probably obvious). If, for example, the date string were 2024/22/04 the format string would be '%Y/%d/%m'.
The date object, held by the variable d, can then be used for many purposes. For example, we can retrieve the year, month, day and day-of-week and date two-months hence:
d.year   #=> 2024
d.month  #=>    4 (January is 1)
d.day    #=>   22 (First day of month is 1)
d.wday   #=>    1 (Sunday is 0)
d >> 2   #=> #<Date: 2024-06-22 ((2460484j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>

One can also use date objects to perform date arithmetic. Suppose, for example, we wanted to know the number of days between the date given by d and July 11, 2026. We could write
r = Date.strptime('20260711', '%Y%m%d') - d    
  #=> (810/1)

We may convert this rational number to an integer:
r.to_i  #=> 810 days


Attempting to convert the date string to a date object also identifies invalid date strings.
For example:
Date.strptime('20230229', '%Y%m%d')
  #=> Date::Error: invalid date

This date was invalid because 2023 was not a leap-year. This obviously is a non-trivial task when using ordinary string methods or functions or a regular expression alone.
